# Proper use of DbFunctions.CreateDateTime()

Tags: c#, .net, entities

I've got a database tabel 'DateExcluded' containing 3 int columns : Year, Month and Day, the latter being the daynumber of the month. I want their combination evaluated in an entity query, to retrieve all rows before one year from current date like so :

```
var l = 
    (from p in c.DateExcluded 
     where
        DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(p.Year, p.Month, p.Day, null, null, null)
        <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
     select p).ToList();
```

This query always returns 0 columns which it shouldn't. Wrong use of DbFunctions.CreateDateTime?

Comment: Use SQL Profiler to capture the SQL executed.

Comment: If you are using it to create a date/time that you can use for comparison purposes (looks like it) then I would say that its probably the wrong use, I would use `... where new DateTime(p.Year, p.Month, p.Day) <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(1) ...`. The db function translates the components into a database function call, and I think should be used more for insertions than comparisons. I'm not 100% on this which is why I'm adding it as a comment.

Comment: EF will generate a string like 2015-10-25 21:15:13.397.

Passing null values will break this format:
    WHERE (convert (datetime2,right(''000'' + convert(varchar(255),   [Extent1].[Year]), 4) + ''-'' + convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[Month]) + ''-'' + convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[Day]) + '' '' + convert(varchar(255), CAST(NULL AS int)) + '':'' + convert(varchar(255), CAST(NULL AS int)) + '':'' + str(CAST(NULL AS float), 10, 7), 121)) <= @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='2016-10-25 20:26:51.1484963'

Comment: @RonBeyer: you will probably have this kind of exception if you pass new dateTime to LINQ: System.NotSupportedException: 'Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.'

Answer (score 2):

> I've got a database tabel 'DateExcluded' containing 3 int columns : Year, Month and Day.

Don't ever create a column for each `year`, `month` and `day`

You're creating a [non-sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) query, also know as the worst performing query you can create.

The correct way is to actually use a `DateTime` field.  Then your query is just correct without any incorrect math possible.

```
var l = 
(from p in c.DateExcluded 
 where
    c.DateExcluded < DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).AddDay(1)
 select p)
.ToList();
```

Comment: Not quite equivalent because he rounds off the time of the date.

Comment: @usr time doesn't matter, since `DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)` is at midnight anway.

Comment: If the time of day is 1min and he is 1 year+1min away this code will miss but his will match. I think you need to add 1 day and use `<`.

Comment: So store them as a DateTime Field with no time.  `.Where(c => c.EventOn >= holiday && c.EventOn < holiday.addDay(1))`. Easy to read and performant.  This is the defacto standard / Best Practices of SQL and date times.  Unless anyone has an extremely good reason not to do this, anything else doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Erik Philips. I want to store holidays of the user as well as recurrent  holidays like the first of january or boxing day. Those days have 0 in the year column so that I dont have to repeat them. The table will not hold many rows so performance is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use DbFunctions.CreateDateTime, avoid null values as it won't work correctly (see why in comment by Ole EH Dufour).
You should pass 0 instead of null, like this:

```
DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(p.Year, p.Month, p.Day, 0, 0, 0)
```